# Set python variable conditionally

Tags: python, variables

I'd like to set a variable based on an other variable. In my case
var1 can be "mean", "sum" or "max" (input parsed from a gui). Based on these strings I want
to set (conditionally) another variable; like: if var1 is "mean" then
var2 = 2, if var1 = "sum" then var2=4, if var1 = "max" then var2 = 6.

What is the best way to do that (for a beginner)? If I use it in a if else procedure I
need to make the variables global to use them also outside the if?
Is there a recommended procedure?

Comment: *"If I use it in a if else procedure I need to make the variables global to use them also outside the if?"* No, but it would make sense to declare the variable beforehand.

Comment: follow the dictionary building process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since python does not have a builtin switch-case statement, a pythonic way to do that is to use a dict:

```
>>> d = {'mean': 2, 'sum': 4, 'max': 6}
>>> var1 = "max"
>>> var2 = d[var1]
>>> var2
6
```

You no longer need to think about the scope of the variable (eventhough it's a good question to think about it !).

Answer (score 6):

Use a dictionary:

```
d = {'mean': 2,
     'sum': 4,
     'max': 6}
var2 = d.get(var1)
```

If `var1` is not contained within `d`, `var2` will default to `None`. If you want another default value:

```
var2 = d.get(var1, 0)
```

Comment: Dammit, beat me by 30 seconds.

Comment: @ChristianWitts That's a long time... I've had 4 second losses before!

Answer (score 2):

How about using dictionaries ?

```
mapping = {'mean': 2
         , 'sum' : 4
         , 'max' : 6
          }
var1 = 'mean'
var2 = mapping[var1]
# or
var2 = mapping.get(var1) # To avoid KeyErrors
```